# What does dict[n] do?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

```
def char_freq(s):
    dict = {}
    for n in s:
        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
    return dict

print(char_freq('google'))
```

I'm a noob and I don't know how this works, specifically the dict[n] += 1 part. what does dict[n] do?

tried just printing the keys and that didn't work either. come to think of it, how does the string get broken into keys / individual letters anyway?

Comment: `dict[n]` means "the key `n` in the dictionary".  This is basic stuff, perhaps you should work through some python tutorials.

Comment: Where did you find this code? This is not an example of well written Python.

Comment: This reimplements a simple version of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we run `char_freq("abbabcbdbabdbdbabababcbcbab")`, then each `n` is a letter in the string "abbabcbdbabdbdbabababcbcbab". So for the first letter ("a"):

- it checks if the "a" is a key in the dictionary already (which it isn't)
- then it creates the key "a" in the dictionary, with the value 1

and so on. If it finds that the key is already in the dictionary, it just increases the value of it by 1. `dict[n] += 1` is the same as `dict[n] = dict[n] + 1`.

The end result of running it is `{'a': 7, 'b': 14, 'c': 3, 'd': 3}`

You can also use this, which might make it easier to understand:

```
def char_freq(s):
    d = {}
    for n in s:
        d[n] = d.get(n, 0) + 1 # get the value of the key "n" in the dictionary, then add 1. If n isn't a key in the dictionary, get 0 instead, then add 1 to that instead
    return d
```

Comment: Don't use `dict` as name for variables. Even if it was used like that in the original question, it's clearly a mistake.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly updated! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use python key word dict as variable name. change dict to other

```
def char_freq(s):
    d = {}
    for n in s:
        if n in d:
            d[n] += 1
        else:
            d[n] = 1
    return d

print(char_freq('google'))
```

1. for n in s: # that means n is g o o g l e successively.
2. 

```
        if n in keys:
            d[n] += 1
        else:
            d[n] = 1
```

this piece means if the dict d does not contain n the value will be set 1 or will be set the original plus 1.

3. here you does not need d.keys(), just use n in d instead.

Answer (score 0):

this counts each letters frequency in the given string.
s is your string

for n in s: gets every character in s and one by one puts them in n, then execute the loop for n

at first dict.keys() return an empty array so keys = []
so for any character that n is not in keys array else will be executed and dict[n]=1

then in next loops if any of characters exist in keys array (lets say your in third loop and keys = ['g', 'o']) then the value of that key will be value=value + 1 ( {'g':1, 'o':1} -> {'g':1, 'o':2} )
at last char_freq returns dict (a dictionary) which gets printed in the output

Answer (score 0):

What this function does is it takes a string in your case it is 'google'
now what it will do is it creates an empty dict {}
It will loop through all the characters in the string
in google
first it will get character 'g' it will check if it exists in the dict if its not it will add the 'g' in dictionary with 1 e.g({'g': 1})
then it will get char 'o' it will do the same and look if its not it will add the 'o' in dictionary with 1 e.g({'o': 1}) and now the present dictionary looks like {'g': 1, 'o': 1}
then it will get char 'o' again but this time it has o in it so it will increment the number of o in the dict e.g({'o': 2}) and now the present dictionary looks like {'g': 1, 'o': 2}
and so on to {'g': 2, 'o': 2, 'l': 1, 'e': 1}